# Bootstrap toggle not working after on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to render bootstrap toggle switch through jquery but it's simply not working after the first time, I'm unable to figure out what to do.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('#showHideButton').change(function(){
      var action = $(this).prop('checked');
      
      $('.container').html('<input id="showHideButton" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">');
      $('.container input').bootstrapToggle();
      
      console.log(action);
     //if(action)
     //   console.log('Inside if');
     //else
     //   console.log('Inside else');
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
   
<br />&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">   
<br /><br />


<div class="container">
  <input id="showHideButton" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
</div>
```

and if I'm using same code without jquery, it is working fine

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
```

check the link
https://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to add this line

`$('#showHideButton  input').bootstrapToggle();`

after your line

`$('#showHideButton').html(‘.......');`

Comment: thanks, brother, this is working but after this, when I toggle the switch then event not triggers on the switch

Comment: @CristianV please enclose the code segment in {} for formatting help see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: @Rajeev Singh, you welcome.

For the second problem, I think your switch will be always regenerated by onclick event on the parent div. 
You must remove the click event on the parent and then the switch will be working.

Comment: @RajeevSingh  you can use this code, but is not the best solution
<code>function callOnClick (e)
{
  console.log($(e).prop('checked'));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    
 
    
 $('#showHideButton').change(function(){   
      $('.container').html('<br /><input id="showHideButton" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" onchange="callOnClick(this)">');
      $('.container input').bootstrapToggle();
      var action = $(this).prop('checked');
   console.log(action);
  
    });
    
});
<code>

Comment: @CristianV Once again Thanks brother I change a little bit code and then code is working absolutely fine 
you can check it in below comment section

Answer (score 1):

The code above appears to be making a checkbox, and it is. Here's an example that makes a switch instead of a checkbox:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showHideButton').click(function() {
    $('#showHideButton').html('<div class="custom-control custom-switch">' +
    '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">' +
    '<label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">' +
    'Dynamic switch</label>' +
    '</div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>A dynamic switch:</p>
  <div id="showHideButton">Click Me!</div>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Comment: no brother instead checkbox it should be bootstrap switch

Comment: @RajeevSingh - OK, I've updated the example to show a switch instead of a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap and in your page you have Bootstrap css loaded, you should insert the correct css classes to the input, in order for the checkbox to be rendered as Bootstrap switch.

Check the Bootrsap examples related to switches (and, look at the class attribute and at the css classes used in the example):

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Toggle this switch element</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" disabled id="customSwitch2">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch2">Disabled switch element</label>
</div>
```

You can find all the examples here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/#switches

Answer (score 0):

Check out this

```js
function callOnClick(e){
    var action = $(e).prop('checked');
    console.log('Inside '+action);

    if(action)
      $('.container').html('<input id="showHideButton" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" onchange="callOnClick(this)">');
    else
      $('.container').html('<input id="showHideButton" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" onchange="callOnClick(this)">');

    $('.container input').bootstrapToggle();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
     
<br />

<div class="container">
  <input id="showHideButton" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" onchange="callOnClick(this)">
</div>
```